# Pandas read multiple excel sheets with a pattern name

Tags: python, pandas

I am using `pandas` and I am trying to read an excel file with multiple sheets.

```
pd.read_excel('PATH', sheet_name=)
```

I only want to read the sheets with the following pattern: `An nnnn`, where `n` is a digit number.
Additionally this file will be updated in the future, so writing the sheetnames one by one is not a good option.

Is it possible, and if yes, how to read multiple excel sheets with the pattern name I described?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can first get a list of the excel sheet names using the [ExcelFile](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/io.html#excel-files) class (and the sheet_names attribute):

```
xl = pd.ExcelFile('foo.xlsx')

xl.sheet_names  # see all sheet names
```

Once you have that you can select from there the sheets that match your pattern:

```
import re
import pandas as pd

dataframes = []
for sheet in xl.sheet_names:
    if re.match('A\d \d{4}', sheet):  # when matching pattern add the dataframe to the list
        dataframes.append(pd.read_excel('foo.xlsx', sheet_name=sheet))
```

You will have all dataframes in a list and can continue your code from there

Comment: Great! Exactly what I wanted. I just thought that `pandas` package had an input that would allow to search for the pattern. Usually the `for` loop consumes more time than a `pandas` function.

Answer (score 1):

You can first search for all files that match a regex pattern, then load each file in with pandas.

```
from pathlib import Path
import re


directory = Path('your/directory/of/csvs/')

file_list = []
for x in directory.iterdir():
   if re.match('A\d \d{3}', x.name):
    pd.read_excel('PATH', sheet_name=x.name)
```

Note, I havent tested that regex.